# Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded with YouTube Data API

Tags: java, android, youtube-api

This is the code for fetching the data:

```
YouTube youtube = new YouTube.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), new HttpRequestInitializer() {
    public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {}
}).setApplicationName("youtube-channel-fetcher").build();
String artist = "";
try{
    artist = youtube.videos().list("snippet").setId(ytID).setKey(Utils.getYouTubeKey()).setFields("items(snippet/channelTitle)").execute().getItems().get(0).getSnippet().getChannelTitle();
} catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ignored){}
```

In response I get the following error:

```
"code" : 403,
"errors" : [ {
"domain" : "usageLimits",
"message" : "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
"reason" : "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
"extendedHelp" : "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
} ],
"message" : "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
```

Answer (score 0):

When I used this app it did the same thing for me until I registered. once I did that the error went away. I don't think the key in the app works.

[project read me](https://github.com/chirags/ytd-android)

[register your app](http://%3CListView%20android:id=%22@android:id/list%22%20android:layout_width=%22match_parent%22%20android:layout_height=%22match_parent%22%20android:paddingBottom=%22110dp%22%20android:clipToPadding=%22false%22%20android:scrollbarStyle=%22outsideOverlay%22%20/%3E)